# AngularJs- If partials can be kept across routing

Tags: angularjs, dom, partial-views, ng-view

I am working on angularjs app. Project multiple partials that loads in ng-view. App is working correctly.

I am trying to optimize app's performance and **want to keep once loaded partials in dom. So that everytime these partials are revisited it should not be reloaded.**

HTML:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

routejs:

```
 $routeProvider.when('route1', {
        template: '1.html',
        controller: '1controller'
    }).when('route2', {
        template: '2.html',
        controller: '2controller'
    })
```

How to prohibit 1html to reload when it was once visited like user visits-

route1-> route2-> route1

So next time users visits route1, html should not reload. Reloading of simple htmls are not costly however html with some images re-loading is costly.

**How to prohibit angular to reload partials everytime?**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How about some example code?  Or at least a plunk?